# Duplicate row for every different entry in one specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a duplicate for every row, but only if the row has a new entry in a specific column and on top want to keep some columns empty then. So the dataframe looks like:

```
number value  area typ
1       10    B     A
2       20    B     A
3       10    B     B
4       20    B     B
5       30    B     B
```

the outcome of my expected dataframe would be:

```
number value  area typ
              B     A
1       10    B     A
2       20    B     A
              B     B
3       10    B     B
4       20    B     B
5       30    B     B
```

so that it gets duplicated based on a new entry of `typ` (a typ which was not in the rows before) and the columns number and value are kept empty.

Comment: what defines new?

Comment: a `typ`which was not in the rows before is "new" for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop duplicate and concat:

```
pd.concat((df.drop_duplicates(['area','typ']).assign(number='',value=''), df)
         ).sort_index(kind='mergesort')
```

Output:

```
  number value area typ
0                 B   A
0      1    10    B   A
1      2    20    B   A
2                 B   B
2      3    10    B   B
3      4    20    B   B
4      5    30    B   B
```

---

**Update**: For several columns that needs to be emptied:

```
cols = ['area','typ']
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(cols)

for col in new_df.columns:
    if col not in cols: new_df[col] = ''

pd.concat((new_df, df)).sort_index(kind='mergesort')
```

Comment: how can I adjust it, when i have more columns which I want to keep empty? Not only `number`and `value`

Comment: Add the additional column names to the `assign` portion, e.g. `assign(col1='', col2='', ...)`  But at some point if you have a significant number of columns to empty, you might want to approach it differently, e.g.: `assign(**{k: '' for k in df.columns.drop(['area', 'typ'])})`