# How to save groupby object in DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame:

```
Name    ID  Month   Shift 
Jon     1   Feb     A
Jon     1   Jan     B
Jon     1   Mar     C
Mike    1   Jan     A
Mike    1   Jan     B
Jon     1   Feb     C
Jon     1   Jan     A
```

And I want to have data like below as groupby, but I'm not able to do so. Please help me.

```
df.groupby(['Name','ID','Shift']).
```

[image]

Comment: Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556060/duplicate-row-for-every-different-entry-in-one-specific-column/62556115#62556115).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[['Jon', 1, 'Feb', 'A'],
          ['Jon', 1, 'Jan', 'B'],
          ['Jon', 1, 'Mar', 'C'],
          ['Mike', 1, 'Jan', 'A'],
          ['Mike', 1, 'Jan', 'B'],
          ['Jon', 1, 'Feb', 'C'],
          ['Jon', 1, 'Jan', 'A']],
    columns=['Name', 'ID', 'Month', 'Shift']
)

empty_rows = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[name, '', '', ''] for name in df['Name'].unique()],
    columns=list(df)
)
df = pd.concat([df, empty_rows])

# this will need to be extended if you have additional months
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], ['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'])
df = df.set_index(['Name','Month']).sort_values(['Name', 'Month'])
```

Reading in the excel file:

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    r'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\stats.xlsx',
    sheet_name='Sheet5', 
    usecols=['Name', 'ID', 'Month', 'Shift']
)
```

Comment: But can we sort also Month ? as its starting form Feb . i want in assending formate and also just one line below of Name  as i have shown in the my query as oputput

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the empty line and sorting by month

Comment: wow Kait .. you are awesome .. Yes its working perfect , but the one doubt on month part . beacuse data will be increased by each month .i mean the month will be also Apr in April and May in May period and so on till December . so can use below code   df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], ['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar','Apr','May','Jun','jul','Aug','sep','oct','Nov','Dec']).. so when we have the data in our dataframe will work accodingly .

Comment: well i tried to add Month Apr only to check if its working or notand i run then i have error  .  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], ['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar','Apr'])... File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Month'

Comment: Interesting, looks like it can not find the column 'Month', can you add `print(df.columns)` before the line that is causing the error (`df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], ['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar','Apr'])`)

Comment: i tired with this .. well let me tell you i am importing the above data Frame trought pd.read _excel . but this is not working also i have added Jan to Dec the month so that as when we recived the data as per month will be auto group by . Please help me .

Comment: I'm happy to help. can you provide the code that I can use to replicate the error?

Comment: below are the stpes i am doing ;  import pandas as pd
>>> df3=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\stats.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet5')
>>> df3=pd.DataFrame(df3)
   >>> print(df3) Name  ID Month  Shift 
0   Jon    1   Feb       A
1   Jon    1    Jan      B
2   Jon    1    Mar      C
3  Mike    1  Jan        A
4   Mike   1    Jan      B
5   Jon    1    Feb      C
6   Jon    1  Jan         A                            and then you have to run above code as yo u already did with keeping in our mind that next month will change so this should take automaticaly for rest of the month automatic

Comment: I don't have access to that file `(r'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\stats.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet5')`, so it is hard to know what is going wrong. My guess is that it is an issue with the column names. I may be able to help further if you post the output for this command `df3.to_dict()`

Comment: well that my files saved on my desktop . i mean u can copy those data and pate in excel and then u can import as pd.read_Excel..you can try with this .. this is simple but  not able to fix it ..do you mean i should data=df3.to_dict(). then this will work ?

Comment: Pls @Kait....please help me... or anyone here #python

Comment: No, printing out the dataframe will not get it to work. the point of printing out the dataframe and posting it here is so I can try to debug the error you are getting.

Comment: when you will be free.. put above data in excel and try it .. this is not working .. while above code that you gave is working but i need to work with this importing it .. you are creating as data as list ..may that is the reason .. really will be happy if u help me

Comment: Try passing in the `usecols` argument. I've updated the answer with an example of what this would look like

Comment: sorry to replay late well i tried with old one thats working friend .. well i tried to unterstand the code first then i appled same way in my file ..its working fine .. but if you see the output , i want to see month just under below name ... (refer my output printscreen ) ... mean same column... can it be possiable then plsease help  me ..

Comment: `df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: x[0] if x[1] == '' else x[1])`

Comment: omg .. YOU ARE EXCELLENTE ...... thanks you so much ........thats works cool .... only header must be display as Name but when we run this header diaspper .. – could u please check

Comment: `df.rename_axis('Name')` You may find this helpful: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html